# Duplicate rule not firing for second time

Tags: apex, lightning

I have a duplicate rule on the Account Name field which is set to Alert & Report.

I already have the below Account Records in the system,

Test,
Test Dup

When I initially create a new record by clicking New with Name as "Test", I see an alert, but when I change the Name to Test Dup (another duplicate name), the record is directly getting created without any alert.

I tried setting DML.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave header in the dml option to false still no luck,

How do I invoke the duplicate rule for a second time as well? or Is there any other way to invoke the duplicate rule through apex for warning?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Instead of a verbal description (a _story_), including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful